# Build Emacs on Ubuntu - libraries not found

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, package-managers

I am trying to install Emacs v. 26.1. When I run `./configure`, I see the following error:

```
configure: error: The following required libraries were not found:
    libXpm libjpeg libgif/libungif libtiff gnutls
Maybe some development libraries/packages are missing?
```

However, they seem to be already there. I tried multiple things, such as:

```
: ~$ apt-cache search gnutls
gnutls-doc - GNU TLS library - documentation and examples
libcurl3-gnutls - easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)
libcurl4-gnutls-dev - development files and documentation for libcurl (GnuTLS flavour)
libgnutls-openssl27 - GNU TLS library - OpenSSL wrapper
```

and

```
:~$ sudo apt install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libcurl4-gnutls-dev is already the newest version (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.6).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 11 not to upgrade.
```

Things seem fine. What am I missing?

Comment: It is better to install the dependencies from ubuntu repo then `./configure`. see [here](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/building_emacs_on_linux.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness,

```
# Install essential build tools
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Second, download Emacs dependencies:

```
# Get all dependencies of a previous Emacs version
sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24

./configure
make
```

Comment: The second apt-get may result in `E: You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list` (`sudo apt-get build-dep emacs26`  - emacs-gtk, version 26.3 installed. On Ubuntu MATE 20.04)

Comment: Can you add information about how to identify `emacsXX`?

Answer (score 13):

As stated in the error message, you actually need the development version of these libraries (tested with Emacs v. 27 on [Ubuntu 19.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.10_(Eoan_Ermine)) (Eoan Ermine)):

```
sudo apt install libxpm-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev libtiff-dev libgnutls28-dev
```

Comment: this solved my problem, Thank you.
emacs 26.3 on Debian 10

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelleyk/emacs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install emacs26
```